Show the formal power series ring is a faithfully flat algebra.
Suppose $S=P^{-1}F[x]$, the localization of $F[x]$ at $P$ where $F$ is a field and $P=(x)\backslash\{0\}$. Let $\hat{S}=F[[x]]$, the formal power series ring. Clearly there is a homomorphism $\Phi: S\to\hat{S}$ by the universal property of localizations.
The Problem: Show that $\hat{S}$ is faithfully flat as an $S$-algebra.
My Attempt: I know two criterion for faithful flatness: $1)$ $\hat{S}$ is flat and $\hat{S}\otimes_S N=0\implies N=0$ for all left $S$-module $N$; $2)$ $\hat{S}$ is flat and that $\hat{S}/\hat{S}I\neq0$ for every left maximal ideal $I\subseteq S$.
Claim 1: $\hat{S}$ is flat.
Proof:
It suffices to show that for every left ideal $I\subseteq S$ the map $\Pi: \mathbf{\hat{S}\otimes_S I\to\hat{S}}$ defined by $f(x)\otimes s\mapsto f(x)\Phi(s)$ is injective. To that end, suppose $\Pi(f(x)\otimes s)=0$, then $f(x)\Phi(s)=0$, i.e., $f(x)=0$ or $\Phi(s)=0$. Note $\Phi$ is injective, thus we have $f(x)=0$ or $s=0$, hence $f(x)\otimes s=0\otimes s=0$ or $f(x)\otimes s=0\otimes s=0$. Thus $\Pi$ is indeed injective. $\blacksquare$
Claim 2: $\hat{S}$ is faithfully flat.
Proof: We use $1)$. Suppose BWOC there exists a left $S$-module $N$ such that $\hat{S}\otimes_S N=0$ and $N\neq0$, then there exists $a\in N$ such that $a\neq0$. Now, $s\otimes a=t\otimes0=0\otimes0$ for all $s, t\in\hat{S}$. Consider $s\otimes a$ and $t\otimes0$, where $s=\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=0}{\Sigma}}x^n$ and $t=\overset{\infty}{\underset{n=0}{\Sigma}}x^{2n+1}$, then $s\otimes a=t\otimes0=0\implies$ Screeching Halt.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

That map is multiplication (sorry, hit send too early) -- multiplication using the copy of $I$ in $\widehat{S}$

@hunter Thank you! Just making sure: $f(x)\otimes s$ in $\hat{S}\otimes_S I$ is mapped to $f(x)\Phi(s)$, correct?

yes that's it!! Just to make the notation a little simpler, might want to convince yourself that $\Phi$ is injective and you can really just think of it as an inclusion.
